# Sum last record in a specific index

Tags: mysql, sum

I can't write a query that works fine. If someone can help me, i'm thankful.

There is a table with multiple records of a specific index. I need to sum the last one of each record.

Table example:

```
+--------+--------+--------+
| id_cop |id_comp | value  |
+--------+--------+--------+
| 1      |   1    |   1000 |
| 1      |   1    |   2000 |
| 1      |   1    |   2200 |
| 2      |   2    |   1100 |
| 3      |   2    |   3000 |
| 3      |   2    |   3400 |
| 4      |   3    |   4000 |
| 5      |   4    |   1100 |
+--------+--------+--------+
```

I need to sum only the last record of each id_cop index WHERE id_comp <= 4.

In this case, the result should be 2200 + 1100 + 3400 + 4000 + 1100.

Any clues?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you define last?

Comment: I'm sorry, there is a column called 'created_at'. I'm using Laravel, but I need the raw query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please give it a try:

```
SELECT 
SUM(t.`value`) AS summedValue
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
    id_cop,
    `value`,
    id_comp,
    IF(@cop_id = id_cop, @rank := @rank + 1, @rank := 0) rankNumber,
    @cop_id := id_cop
    FROM coptable , (SELECT @cop_id := -1, @rank := 0) var
    WHERE id_comp <= 4
    ORDER BY id_cop , created_at DESC
) AS t
WHERE t.rankNumber = 0
GROUP BY t.rankNumber;
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/59756/1/0)

**Note:** Here I've used table name as `coptable`. Replace `coptable` by yours.